# Mongodb correct aggregation with $facet

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, aggregate

I have some array in DB. With field 'rate' (values: 0 - 100), projectId etc.

I need a result as:

```
{
  totalCount: 33,
  suspicious: [...],
  other: [...],
  totalSuspiciousCount: 22,
  totalOtherCount: 11,
}
```

suspicious - is array of 10 elements or less with rate > 50

other - is an array of 10 elements or less with rate <= 50

I created some aggregated query, but I guess there is some way to improve it:

```
sails.models.observable.aggregate([
  { $match: { projectId: ObjectId(projectId) } },
  { $sort: { suspiciousRate: -1 } },
  {
    $facet: {
      totalCount: [{ $count: 'count' }],
      suspicious: [{ $match: { rate: { $gt: 50 } } }, { $limit: 10 }],
      other: [{ $match: { rate: { $lte: 50 } } }, { $limit: 10 }],
      totalSuspiciousCount: [{ $match: { rate: { $lte: 50 } } }, { $count: 'count' }],
      totalOtherCount: [{ $match: { rate: { $gt: 50 } } }, { $count: 'count' }]
    }
  }
])
```

Comment: What's the issue with the above one?

Comment: I'm not quite sure but, sounds like query optimization request.

Comment: It works as expected. I think it's not the best way to do it. Maybe it's possible to optimize.

Comment: Independent from mongodb, maybe if you sort after you apply facet, you may get performance improvement since you will have less results to sort.